# Unity ads not working on android device

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

imported unity ads asset from unity asset store. This asset working well when imported a new project. I have a game project and still working on this project. Imported a asset store like a previous. Ads working well on unity player but not working on android device. Logcat output is bellow. I am not changed any line or word on asset.

```
 I/Unity   (26980): IsolatedStorageException: Could not find a part of the path "/data/app/com.omr-1/base.apk/Standard Assets/UnityAds/Textures/test_unit_800.png".
 I/Unity   (26980):   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x001f9] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:290 
 I/Unity   (26980):   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 I/Unity   (26980):   at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:363
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't solve the problem and i don't know why asset is not working on my project. Fixed ads code and demo ad shown but demo video ads not working again. So, created a new project and add unity ads from asset store. After this things(ads works now) and copied my solution directory to new project directory. It works. Probably asset package didn't change some options or configurations on my existing project.